# Allowing link only to be accessed from a specific page?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to have a page that can only be accessed from approved websites but I don't know exactly how to approach it. Would I just have to provide like a snippet of PHP code that generates a random key and attaches it to the URL and that key is only valid for one access?

Or would it be possible to have a cookie set at the other domain, and then read at the final destination?  Maybe it would be a 1px iframe at the initial page?

Or am I just trying to do something that's never going to work?

Comment: Do you have control over both the originating and destination websites? In that case I'd use a cookie that's cryptographically selected and coordinated between the sites (at least passively, as in cookies must be validly signed, have a close timestamp, and not be blatant duplicates)

Comment: I don't have direct control over the other websites, but I could say, in order to use my website and allow your users to use it, you'd have to add this php widget to your website and I could do server-side scripting that way. How would I handle cookies cross-domains? Iframe?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#window.name, where it states: "All current web browsers can store a fairly large amount of data (2–32 MB) via JavaScript using the DOM property window.name. This data can be used instead of session cookies and is also cross-domain. The technique can be coupled with JSON/JavaScript objects to store complex sets of session variables[51] on the client side." The cryptographically-signed authentication data can be stored there/

Comment: You can check $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to check host directed this user to your site but I think it

Comment: @AliR. This is not a reliable method because this data comes from the client which can send any data it wants.

Comment: What kind of misuse are you trying to defend against? If a client fraudulently pretends to come from an approved site, is that a problem or not?

Comment: @adhominem, I just need a method to secure a page without the need to have login credentials for each user, or any login for that matter.  Another option I thought was to maybe do a POST send each time they click on a link, and my page would only allow them in if the POST contained a specific key.  I know that can be faked as well, but it probably wouldn't be worth the effort to figure out that it authenticates based on POST key, and then try to figure out the key needed.

Comment: @zen Then you actually could simply check the referrer. It can be faked as easily as the post, but is less intrusive for the approved sites (they do not need to change anything).

Comment: True. I'll have to think about this for a bit more.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, we were able to clarify that...

> I [zen] just need a method to secure a page without the need to have login credentials for each user, or any login for that matter. Another option I thought was to maybe do a POST send each time they click on a link, and my page would only allow them in if the POST contained a specific key. [...]

Since detecting fraudulent accesses is not an issue, I would suggest you simply check the [http referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) against a list of approved sites (and/or pages). It's non-invasive for the approved sites and offers no worse security than a fixed post-token you check.

In PHP, the referrer is in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable, if available.

Answer (score -2):

ok so here it is answer

```
<?php
$server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];          //Getting Server name
$site_name = "http://$server";              //Creating Website URL from SERVER_NAME
$url_allowed = array("http://www.allowed1.com", "http://www.allowed2.com"); //Add Allowed Website list Here
if(in_array($site_name,$url_allowed)){
echo "<a href='***your link here***'>This is Link</a>";
}else{
echo "This Link is Not Allowed For Your Site";
}
?>
```

Comment: -1 because this is not solving the problem, instead, it does search the server's name in a pre-defined array. How does that have anything to do with the OP's question?

Comment: This seems to be validating something different in its entirety.

Comment: After talking to @zen, it seems that a referrer check is actually a reasonable way to go about this. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @adhominem Sorry to say, but I rollbacked the previous version. Edits are not meant for new ideas or bigger improvements (except if the question is a community wiki). Please post a new answer ;)

Comment: @ComFreek Fine, I'll do that then